# how to configure filebeat configured as agent in kubernetes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, devops, filebeat, elk

I am trying to add ELK to my project which is running on kubernetes. I want to pass by filebeat -> logstach then elastic search. I prepared my filebeat.yml file and in my company the filebeat is configured as an agent in the cluster which i don't realy know what it means? I want to know how to configure the filebeat in this case ? just adding the file in the project and it will be taken into considiration once the pod started or how does it work ?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html 

If with agent you mean Elastic Agent then the story is different

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Filebeat in some ways.

1 - You can configure it using the DeamonSet, meaning each node of your Kubernetes architecture will have one POD of Filebeat. Usually, in this architecture, you'll need to use only one filebeat.yaml configuration file and set the inputs, filters, outputs (output to Logstash, Elasticsearch, etc.), etc. In this case, your filebeat will need root access inside your cluster.

2 - Using Filebeat as a Sidecar with your application k8s resource. You can configure an emptyDir in the Deployment/StatefulSet, share it with the Filebeat Sidecar, and set the Filebeat to monitor this directory.